How to reduce the number of re render in react when the component is complex like nested component?
I'm using React with Redux Toolkit for state management in my app, which has a nested component structure. Let's say I have three main components: a main wrapper component, an item component, and a child item component. The child item component can have multiple nested child components as well. Both the item and child item components use useState, useEffect, and useSelector to manage and retrieve data from Redux.
All the data is stored in Redux as an array of objects, with each object containing a level field (which indicates the nesting level) and a prevId field (which indicates the parent data). I loop through the Redux data in the main wrapper component to display it using the item component. Within the item component, I call the child item component for any direct children (based on prevId). This structure is somewhat similar to a linked list of components.
The issue I'm facing is that every item or child item is rendered multiple times (I've verified this using console.count to track the number of re-renders) when I switch to edit mode, even if I haven't made any changes yet.
Does anyone have a solution or guidance for a similar type of problem?
I've already implemented useMemo for possible values inside the components and React.memo for the components themselves to prevent unnecessary re-renders, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.
wrapper component
const WrapperComponent = () => {
const ItemDataRedux = useSelector(selectItemDataRedux);
const ItemListData = useDebounce(ItemDataRedux, 450);

const memoizedItemData = useMemo(() => {
  return ItemListData?.filter((obj: Item) => obj.level === 1);
}, [ItemListData]);

return (
  <div>
    {memoizedItemData?.map((item: Item, index: number) => (
      <ItemComponent
        key={`${item.id}`}
        idElement={item.idElement}
        name={item.name ?? ""}
        nextLogic={item.nextLogic}
        // in item component, i name it as nextLogicServer from props
        listItemChild={item?.listItemChild ?? []}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
  );
};
export default WrapperComponent;

item component
  const ItemDataRedux = useSelector(selectItemDataRedux);
  const [nextLogic, setNextLogic] = useState<nextLogicType>({
    GoNextLogic: nextLogicServer?.GoNextLogic ?? null,
  });
  const [nameElement, setNameElement] = useState<string>(name || "");
  if (name === "item 1") {
    // this is where i count how many times the component rerender
    console.count("run on at first item")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // update the local nextLogic where parent changes
    setNextLogic({
        ...nextLogic,
        GoNextLogic: nextLogicServer?.GoNextLogic ?? null,
    });
  }, [nextLogicServer?.GoNextLogic]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const SaveData = () => {
        // update the data in redux selectItemDataRedux by idElement
        dispatch(
            updateElementByIdElement({
                idElement,
                nextLogic,
            })
        );
    };
    // v1 directly update
    // SaveData();

    // v2 delay by 0.2 second then update
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        SaveData();
    }, 200);

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [nextLogic, idElement]);

updateElementByIdElement is for updating the parent data for const ItemDataRedux = useSelector(selectItemDataRedux);

This code doesn't look complex at all... is there any actual performance issue to fix? What/where/how exactly are you measuring performance to determine there is a problem? We need better details and a clear goal.

The main problem is the rerendering part even if i do not update anyting, the item component just rerender multiple times. The objective is reducing the number of rerender. I'm using console.count to determine how many times the component rerender. It can be up to 100 times of each component from the console.count.
There is part in item component that update the redux. If the redux is updated, then  possibly the all items component is rerendered again.

I'm doubting your method of determining actual renders to the DOM, e.g. the expensive part. If you are just console logging in the function body then this isn't an accurate measure of how many times a component is actually rendered. Can you [edit] to show us exactly how you are measuring performance/renders?

I just updated and addded how i count the rerender part

Component functions being called (which is what you measure with console.count() and console.log()) doesn't mean they cause renders to the DOM.

Yeah, it's what I thought. Move that console.count into a useEffect hook to try and collect a more accurate render count. That said, it's perfectly normal for React to rerender when it needs to. Are you observing any actual performance issue? If so, you should run a performance audit in the browser's devtools to see what the issue and any bottlenecks are so you aren't just thrashing around guessing what the cause of the issue is.

Look you use idElement in useeffect dependency and you map a data in there if there's 100 of data you pass through idElement it can be re render useeffect and it's corosponding functions 100 times for that reason it's possible to react showing you re render error or the project is crashed.

Oh i see, i think i should better remove that cause idElement is never change and always exist. What about the part updateElementByIdElement ? it update the redux. If i have 100 item and one of the items is doing the logic updateElementByIdElement, dont you think its gonna rerender the others 99 item component ? Should i change the logic flow on how i update the data ?

No, it certainly appears that the idElement prop is referenced in the effect callback and should be included in the dependency array.
